# log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Everything works just as fine. But showing this error.

My log4j.properties file like :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p    %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
 log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Thanks in advance. Just tell me how to do it. I just want log file on daily rolling .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DailyRollingFileAppender` doesn't support MaxFileSize, `RollingFileAppender` does.

`DailyRollingFileAppender` is for rolling files based on the date and time of the log entry, so if you want to use it you should remove the `MaxFileSize` property.

Comment: Then what should i do instead of that..?? Or just remove it

Comment: @MdShifatulIslam You should remove it, I assume you don't need files to be split by size if you split them by date.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code to

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

from

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

and it worked fine in log4j.properties file