# Getting error from Log4j.properties log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

Tags: log4j

log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
What does this mean, what causes it, and how should you fix it?

```
 # initialize root logger with level ERROR for stdout and file
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout,file
    # set the log level for these components
    log4j.logger.com.endeca=DEBUG
    log4j.logger.com.endeca.itl.web.metrics=INFO

    # add a ConsoleAppender to the logger stdout to write to the console
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    # use a simple message format
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

    # add a FileAppender to the logger file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    # create a log file
    log4j.appender.file.File=E:\\temp\\GAPN.log
    # take backup periodically
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2KB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10

    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    # use a more detailed message pattern
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Probably duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236288/log4jwarn-no-such-property-maxfilesize-in-org-apache-log4j-dailyrollingfileap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4j:WARN No such property \[maxFileSize\] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236288/log4jwarn-no-such-property-maxfilesize-in-org-apache-log4j-dailyrollingfileap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appender 'file' is of type [`FileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html). `FileAppender` does not have a field `MaxFileSize`. This is a property of `RollingFileAppender` class, which is a subclass of `FileAppender` and allows for log rotation based on size.